# Cython: How to export C++ class to .hpp header instead of C .h header

Tags: python, c++, header, cython, transpiler

This works fine in .pxd file:

```
cdef public:
    struct foo:
        float bar
```

But this doesn't work:

```
cdef public:
    class foo:
        float bar # Syntax error in simple statement list
```

This works but Cython is still making `struct` instead of `class` and the resulting file is .h file instead of .hpp (or .hh) file:

```
cdef public:
    cppclass foo:
        float bar
```

My file is called `mod.pyx` and Cython transpiles the `cppclass` right above as:

```
#ifndef __PYX_HAVE__mod
#define __PYX_HAVE__mod

#include "Python.h"
struct foo;
struct foo {

  /* "mod.pyx":21
 *
 * cdef public:
 *     cppclass foo:             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *         float bar
 *
 */
  float bar;
};
```

**How to make real C++ output from Cython transpilation**? I mean .hpp or .hh files with `class` keyword inside. It's possible to use a separate C++ header file instead but I would like to make the source code fully Cython.

The transpile command is:
`cython3 -3 --cplus --fast-fail mod.pyx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to define C++ class (not the Python extension type 'class') in Cython only; it is still transpiled to `.h` file **as `struct` but** **with methods inside**:

```
# Declaration
cdef public:
    cppclass foo:
        float bar
        foo() # Constructor
        method() # Sample method

# Implementation
cdef cppclass foo:
    method():
        cdef foo* p = this # 'this' can be used
        print(p.bar+1) # Test
```

There are some notes:

- The nullary constructor is a must, Cython says so

  - This doesn't require constructor: cdef foo* f = new foo()
  - This requires a constructor: cdef foo f = foo()

    - Or error: `no constructor found for C++  type 'foo'`
- No overloads in Python, which applies to Cython and so no constructor overloads (?); properties to be set by a method instead